# how to use $scope.arr.filter in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to use filter method in angular with `moment js` .When I filled these field on my fields an click search button .It show no result .It should show one result .

```
"TO" : "DEL"
"FROM" :"PNQ"
"DEPART Date" : "10-01-2017"
```

here is my code

https://plnkr.co/edit/k4FBxqufETslgYxm4zEx?p=preview

```
$scope.searchClick =function(){
  if($scope.fromStation!='' && $scope.toStation!='' && $scope.departDate !=''){
    $scope.names = $scope.defaultNames.filter(function(item){
       var time1 = moment(item.flight_date, "DD-MM-YYYY");
       var time2 = moment($scope.departDate, "DD-MM-YYYY");
       console.log(moment(time1).isSame(time2))
      return item.to_station === $scope.toStation 
      && item.from_station === $scope.fromStation
      &&  moment(time1).isSame(time2)
    })
  }
}
```

This line gives true on first object .but not shown in output why ?

```
console.log(moment(time1).isSame(time2))
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more. I am not getting your question. Is it that your sample is breaking due to the date mismatch?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you got it a bit wrong. The $filters in Angular 1 are different from the filter in JavaScript Arrays. The thing you have done above should return an object not True or False as your return statement is doing. You can try modifying it a bit so as to return the values in first place and then the date time issue can be looked into. More over the plunkr you shared does not have the code your have mentioned in the question.

Have a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control It might be helpful